# EKS volume in multiple availability zones

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-ebs

I have a large (>100Gib) of static data needed by a container running an an EKS cluster. I currently have it stored in an EBS volume. I start testing with 1 node in the cluster in availability zone us-west-2b. The EBS volume is in the same zone. My volume def looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: large-data-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 150Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ""
  csi:
    driver: ebs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: vol-928348292
    fsType: ext4
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone
              operator: In
              values:
                - us-west-2b
```

The volume claim is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: large-data-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 150Gi
```

I can mount the volume using that claim. However, if I scale up a node group and it creates a node in us-west-2c I can't mount the data because it's in a different zone.

How can I fix this? Can I have multiple volumes in different zones built from the same snapshot and have a single volume (or multiple volumes and a single claim) so it uses the correct EBS volume for the node's zone? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "How can I fix this?" - to fix what? Can you explain more about what you want to achieve? What are you trying to do? Yes, you can have multiple volumes in different zones, but do you really want the same data? In the cloud native world, it's common that the application itself replicate data - not "smart" nodes - but it really depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: First of all, you need to change `ReadWriteOnce` to `ReadWriteMany` in order to have it mounted to multiple pods.

Comment: Jonas I thought I was clear enough...I have large static data that's needed by the container. It's impractical to bake into an image because it's quite large and pull times would be long. It's also data that can't be put in a pubic image repos. It's also time limiting put in s3 and download each time.

Comment: As @gohmc has mentioned EFS/FSx (regional services) seem to be more appropriate for this use case instead of EBS (zonal service)